# How to speed up my python code with NUMBA?

Tags: python, performance, jit, numba

I try to speed up my code but I get an error? how can I fix the code to increase the speed of iteration? @njit doesn't work? 
TXT files size 20 MB. A lot of time is spent for opening files.

```
import requests
import random
from numba import njit, cuda 

filenames = ['input7.txt', 'input8.txt']
@njit
def run():
    try:
        while 5 > 1:
            browser = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) ' +\
                'AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) ' +\
                'Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36'
            headers = {'User-Agent': browser}
            pageNum1 = random.randrange(1,1000000)
            pageNum2 = random.randrange(1,1000000)
            fullurl = ['http://localhost/'+str(pageNum1),'http://localhost/'+str(pageNum2)]

            for url in fullurl:
                html = requests.get(url=url, headers=headers).text
                print (url)
                for filename in filenames:
                    with open(filename) as f:
                        for line in f:
                            if line.rstrip() in html:
                                print(f'Find "{line}" on the page {url}')
                                with open('find.txt', 'a') as appendFile:
                                    appendFile.write('{}\n'.format(url))
                                    appendFile.write('{}\n'.format(line))
                                return

    except (ValueError):
        print ("Break")

run()
```

Error from my cmd:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nl6TS.jpg)

Comment: Just wondering... under what circumstances are you envisaging 5 might suddenly become less than or equal to 1?

Comment: https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Fortran#Misquoted "should the value of PI change"

Comment: The problem is that you are using a lot of Python objects. Numba will not be all that good at speeding up your code as you have to use it in object mode, even in the innermost part of your nested looping. Perhaps you do have a better shot with Cython. In any case, the gain will be marginal, unless you modify your code substantially.

Comment: @norok2 what needs to be changed in the code so that the benefit is significant?

Comment: Use bytes instead of strings for start

Comment: If you want your code to run faster, you need to measure what is taking the majority of the time. If you optimise some aspect that is only responsible for 1% of the total time such that it is twice as fast, overall your program will still take 99.5% of the original time. If you measure your program, you will almost certainly find that 80+% of the time is the latency in waiting for the `requests.get()` so I would suggest that rather than trying Numba, you look at multi-threading the requests so you incur all the response latencies in parallel.

Comment: @MarkSetchell 80+% of the time is the latency in waiting for the open filenames (input7+input8 =20mb)

Comment: 20mb (millibits) or 20MB (megabytes)? If you have new information about filesizes and timing, please click `edit` under your question and make sure people can see all the relevant information without wading through the comments. Thank you.

Comment: 20MB certainly.